# Kiel "esperantigi" Stack Exchange? / How to "esperantize" Stack Exchange?

Tags: translation, resources

Multe da retejojn havas klarajn Esperantajn ekvivalentojn de siaj nomoj, kiujn oni vere uzas, ekz. *fejsbuko*, *jutubo*, *vikipedio*. Ŝajnas al mi, ke traduki aŭ transliteri "Stack Exchange" ne povus krei iun ajn kompreneblan. Sed tamen, ĉu ekzistas iu ajn akceptebla esperanta esprimo por ĝin, aŭ ni nur povas uzi la anglan nomon?

Mi pensus, ke "Stack" (estanta parto de originala "Stack Overflow") devus verŝajne resti tiel, sed "Exchange" povus principe havi ian similan vorton en Esperanto. Aŭ ĉu Esperanto ankaŭ havas vorton por la komputila termino "stack"?

Comment: Laŭ la komputada leksikono "stack" estas "stako" kaj "stack overflow" estas "staktroo" (http://bertilow.com/div/komputada_leksikono/SO.html#STAKO).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Jen mia propono: *Stakinterŝanĝo*.

Comment: Kaj ĝi aspektas populare!